# When should (( )) be preferred over [ ] for specifying conditions?

Tags: command-line, bash

In bash shell scripting, when should we prefer (( )) over test command for specifying conditions? Moreover, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: I suppose this is too generic. Ask on [unix.se].

Comment: [Difference in Bash between IF statements with parenthesis and square brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12765340/4023950) on http://Stackoverflow.com

Comment: [How to use double or single bracket, parentheses, curly braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces) on http://Stackoverflow.com

Comment: [Conditions in bash scripting (if statements)](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/conditions-in-bash-scripting-if-statements/) on https://linuxacademy.com